# I want to create multiple csv files from the data in the main csv file

Tags: csv

I am not an expert, so I apologize in advance for my question (which I'm certain is fairly basic for a power user).  I have 350+ rows in an excel file. Instead of copying and pasting the individual rows to create the unique csv files I need, I was hoping that there was a way to do this with a macro?

Comment: Idea for someone else to create an answer from: Activate AutoFilter, detect which rows are visible, save them to a text (csv)-file.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

Save the whole Excel file as csv named myfile.csv

In the same folder create file split.bat with content:

```
@echo off
set /a c=0
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (myfile.csv) do ( 
  set /a c=c+1   
  echo %%A > !c!.csv
)
```

Run `split.bat` and you will get 350+ csv files with one line inside

Comment: That echo will create a trailing space on everey line. I'd put the redirection in front and include the original filename. `>myfile_!c!.csv echo:%%A`

Answer (score 0):

Not going to write the code.

But If you just want to be able to save only visible lines from an open excel worksheet/csv opened in excel to a new .csv and you don't want to or can't code it yourself, the quick and dirty solution is to create a workbook and record a macro to do it for you.

Here's one possible way - it isn't elegant code, but it works:

1. Create a workbook with two worksheet pages
2. Click record macro
3. Import data from the csv onto the first page
4. Create the filter
5. Set the filter parameters
6. Select rows down to below the last record (and any foreseeable future records)
7. Copy
8. Paste on second worksheet page
   (By default, only visible lines are copied over)
9. Export second page to .csv
10. Stop recording

The code it generates is kinda awful, but the macro will work.

Bear in mind that it will always set the filter parameters to what you used when recording. So if you want different .csv files using different filter parameters, you will have to create more than one macro or alternatively do the import and filter manually every time you use it and click record the macro only from step 6. above (select rows)

You can go through the recorded macro and clean up the code and also make changes to make it more versatile - or at least look at what the code looks like if you've never coded in VB or VBA

Answer (score -1):

You can directly save it as .csv file. Click on **File** and choose **Save As**.Under **Save as type**, choose **CSV (Comma delimited)**. Click Save.

==================
Sorry that I misunderstood your question before. You could use the following python script to achieve your goal.

```
#! /usr/bin/python

from xlrd import open_workbook

f=open_workbook('source.xlsx')
sheets=f.sheets()
for sheet in sheets:
    for r in range(sheet.nrows):
        filename=str(r)+'.csv'
        file=open('%s' % filename,'w+')
        for c in range(sheet.ncols):
            value=str(sheet.cell(r,c).value)
            file.write(value)
            if c!=(sheet.ncols-1):
                file.write(',')
        file.close()
```

Comment: Hi, thanks.  I understand how to do the above.  My question is how do I take the the rows in the excel sheet and create a unique csv file.  Example data in the row :  name, department, city.   I have 350 rows and need 350 unique csv files.

Comment: sorry, misunderstood your question. Here is a python script you can use to achieve your goal. Tested it and it worked for me.